# 2D geometric relation in a rectangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, rectangles

I'm trying to implement the Sakoe & Chiba's global constraint for the Dynamic Time Warping algorithm but I'm stuck with a geometrical problem :

I'm trying to find the value of *d* given *a*, *b* and *c*.

[image: relation between a, b, c and d]

I think I have to use Pythagore but I miss a value to use it...

Comment: Is the distance on the right hand side from the top right corner down to the second diagonal intersection equal to $b$, perhaps? It isn't exactly so on your diagram, but if that were the case the you could calculate the other quantities.

Comment: Sorry, its an unfortunate coincidence, this isn't the case because **c** can be longer.

Comment: Hah, in any case, I didn't realize that you had $c$, I thought you had to calculate it - so the answers given look good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start, notice that $$c = d\sin\arctan\left(\frac b a \right)$$
So $$d = c \sec\arctan\left(\frac b a \right) = c{\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac b a \right)^2}}$$

---

Alternatively, if you compare angles, you can see that two of the triangles are similar, so $$\dfrac{d}{c} = \frac{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{a} $$

Comment: Thanks! But It doesn't work for _a_ != _b_. Did you interchange _b_ and _a_?

Comment: @Nico I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Purely by similar triangles,
$\frac{c}{d}
=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
$.
No trig functions needed.